# MySQL Select where Value = 0

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, where-clause

---

**TL;DR**

Why `SELECT * FROM title_included = 0` returns **one line** ?

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person_task WHERE title_included = 0;
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+----------------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | location | keyword | industry | years_of_experience | language | first_name | last_name | zip_code | title_included        | title_excluded | title_scope | function | company | company_size | seniority_level | tenure_at_company | total_results | last_result_scraped | elapsed | is_done | last_page_scraped | total_pages | creation_time       | scraping_time       |
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+----------------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 0        | 0       | 0        | 0                   | 0        | 0          | 0         | 0        | Global IT procurement | 0              | CURRENT     | 0        | 0       | C            | 0               | 0                 |            12 |                  12 | 86.5676 |       0 |                 1 |           1 | 2019-11-02 16:08:51 | 2019-11-02 15:12:34 |
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+----------------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person_task WHERE title_included = "0";
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**0**

```sql
SELECT * FROM person_task WHERE title_included = 0
```

This first query returns **one line**.

---

**"0"**

```sql
SELECT * FROM person_task WHERE title_included = "0"
```

This second query returns **no line**.

---

**Table**

Here is my `person_task` table structure. `title_included` specifically here is `MEDIUMTEXT`.

```sql
mysql> DESCRIBE person_task;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| location            | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| keyword             | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| industry            | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| years_of_experience | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| language            | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name          | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name           | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| zip_code            | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title_included      | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title_excluded      | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title_scope         | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| function            | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| company             | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| company_size        | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| seniority_level     | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tenure_at_company   | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| total_results       | mediumint(9) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_result_scraped | mediumint(9) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| elapsed             | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_done             | tinyint(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_page_scraped   | tinyint(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| total_pages         | mediumint(9) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| creation_time       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| scraping_time       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
25 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you please read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)  and stop using images? ..

Comment: Why would you compare a string such as `Global IT procurement` with `'0'` or `0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `WHERE title_included = 0`

You are comparing a string to an integer. When doing this, MySQL converts the string to a numeric datatype. Unless your string starts with a number, the result is `0`. Hence all records match.

> `WHERE title_included = "0"` (note: should be `'0'`)

Here you are doing string comparison. Things work as you would expect.

Bottom line: know your datatypes; pass the proper datatype in the queries to avoid implicit conversion. If you want to compare a string, compare it *with a string*.

---

This is [explained in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html):

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and numeric operands takes places as a comparison of floating-point numbers.

Here is an example of what happens under the hood when you do string to integer comparison:

```
select cast('a' as float)
```

```
| cast('a' as float) |
| -----------------: |
|                  0 |
```

```
select cast('1a' as float)
```

```
| cast('1a' as float) |
| ------------------: |
|                   1 |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65fbe20e86bc6f47a483276a0a57e8d7)**

Comment: Why *all records match* with `= 0` ?

Comment: Because all strings get converted to a number, and becomes `0`... See the examples in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For literal value mysql use  single quote

```
SELECT * FROM person_task WHERE title_included = '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because 0 and "0" are not the same, that is 0 === "0" is false, 0 is an integer and "0" is a string

Comment: Also `===` is not a thing in SQL it is just simply `=` when you see [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uy4PE3UgEAu9C6KAZKvGPX/0) you will be shocked how MySQL auto casts datatype as `0 = "0"` is `1` (true) in MySQL. .

Comment: Ya, I know there is no === in MySQL, was just using a shorthand way of expressing what I was saying. I have just checked the fiddle, amazing.

Comment: *"was just using a shorthand way of expressing what I was saying"* When somebody reads `===` he or she needs to know that that is a PHP operator and is used as equal value check where the datatype also has to be the same.. And PHP is not tagged here.